# trying to run commend on cmd throw c++ using createprocces (API)?

Tags: c++, api, createprocess

```
bool execute()
{
    STARTUPINFO si;
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi;
    bool flag = true;
    ZeroMemory(&si, sizeof(si));
    si.cb = sizeof(si);
    ZeroMemory(&pi, sizeof(pi));
    string f = "dir desktop"
    if (CmdLine.parameter != "")
    {
        LPSTR l1 = const_cast<char *>(f.c_str());
        CreateProcess(NULL, l1, NULL, NULL, false, 0, NULL, NULL, &si, &pi);
        flag = true;
        //  WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);

        //  // Close process and thread handles. 
        //  CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
        //  CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
        //}
    }
    return flag;
}
```

I'm trying to run cmd command by visual studio.
I'm using createprocces (API) in order to run this thing
but I can't understand why it doesn't run anything.

Comment: Why is `flag` set to `true` in two places, and never to `false`?

Answer (score 1):

`dir` is a command understood by `cmd.exe`, it's not a program you can execute.

You can try the command `cmd /k "dir desktop"`, properly expressed as a C++ string.

E.g.,

```
auto execute()
    -> bool
{
    STARTUPINFO si = { sizeof( si ) };
    PROCESS_INFORMATION pi = {};
    string f = "cmd /k \"dir desktop\"\0";
    bool const ok = !!CreateProcess( 0, &f[0], 0, 0, false, 0, 0, 0, &si, &pi );
    if( !ok ) { return false; }
    WaitForSingleObject(pi.hProcess, INFINITE);
    CloseHandle(pi.hProcess);
    CloseHandle(pi.hThread);
    return true;
}
```

Note how the calls to `ZeroMemory` have been replaced with C++ initialization.

Just by letting the compiler do its job you get shorter, more clear code that is more likely correct, and just as efficient (possibly more). Win win win.

Disclaimer: code not reviewed by compiler.

---

If the intent is to list the contents of the user's desktop folder, then note that `dir desktop` doesn't do that. As an interactive command in the command interpreter you could use `dir %userprofile%\desktop`, and that also works via the Windows Run-dialog. Depending on the command interpreter's behavior for command line arguments it may work directly via `CreateProcess`, or not.

---

Generally, when using Windows API level functions it's preferable to use the `wchar_t`-based text based functions, i.e. define `UNICODE` before including `<windows.h>` (or use the `...W` functions explicitly).

Answer (score 0):

If you call [`CreateProcess()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682425%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) with the first parameter set to NULL, then you have to make sure that `l1` starts with the module name to call.

As `dir` is an internal command of the command processor and not an executable, you have to use `cmd` as module name and give the rest of the parameter [as cmd expects them](http://ss64.com/nt/cmd.html).

So try the following:

```
 string f = "cmd /c=dir desktop";
```